# I am facing this problem when I am connecting the supabase from Python

Tags: python, supabase

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'supabase'

Code below:

```
import supabase


# Get the Supabase credentials from environment variables
supabase_url = "https://XXXX.supabase.co"
supabase_key = "XXXX"

# Create a Supabase client
client = supabase.Client(supabase_url, supabase_key)

table_name = "userlocation"
table = Table(table_name, supabase)


columns = ['address', 'city', 'state','poscode']  # Replace with your actual column names

response = table.select(columns=columns)

if response["status_code"] == 200:
    data = response["data"]
    print(data)  # Do something with the retrieved data
else:
    error = response["error"]
    print("Error:", error)
```

My python version is 3.11.4

I have try reinstall it again but it doesn't work, even after I install supabase-py

Comment: How did you install supabase ?

Comment: You don't appear to be importing supabase